# Multiple slots in 1 sentence with amazon lex

Tags: amazon-lex

I'm trying to create a bot for analytics purpose. Basically, this bot retrieve the name of the website, the metric name and the range date. It works fine, but with multiple questions ("what is the website ?" / "what is the metric ?" / "from when" / "to when").

I would like to know if it's possible to configure 1 slot for all the data like:

```
"I would like to know about {metric} for {website} from {dateStart} to {dateEnd}"
```

Comment: Do you want _1 slot for all the data_? or multiple slots in an intent?

Comment: I would like to have 1 slot for all the data AND 1 slot per data. Currently, the "1 slot per data" is done, but i cannot have the "1 slot for all the data" working.